# How to convert Byte Array to image using itextPdf and display in pdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext

How to convert byte array to image in itext pdf and display in pdf.
This is what i am doing but i am getting nullpointer exception..

```
    Base64 decoder = new Base64();
    byte[] imageByte = decoder.decode(imageInBase64EncodedString);
        Image image = null;
        try {
            image = Image.getInstance(imageByte);
        } catch (BadElementException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            image.scalePercent(15f);  <-----Here i am getting NullPointer Exception
            image.scaleAbsoluteWidth(520f);
            image.setAbsolutePosition(40f,725f);
            document.add(image);
       }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

I am not understanding why image is not created even i pass them bytes.

Comment: Did any of the `printStackTrace` calls above trigger?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Ty for replying guys @mkl no.

Comment: @DanCornilescu Ty for commenting but i am not asking for nullpointer exception. I meant why image is null when i pass them byte array.

Comment: Please share the value of `imageInBase64EncodedString`; otherwise we can't answer your question.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie can i mail you??

Comment: No you can't, unless you are a customer of iText Software (in which case you have access to a closed ticketing system).

Comment: Though your code may be running in an App Engine application, it doesn't really relate that product so I've proposed an edit to remove that tag.  Regarding your actual error, I'm in agreement with @That Guy Lionel that the evidence points to the input string being the source of this problem.  I would suggest verifying that this is a proper input string first and retesting your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is most likely the String value you're passing in, as it's very likely you're running into an exception for bad formatting in the value.

I've tried your example, using a BASE64 String example from PasteBin (http://pastebin.com/bfc1E1NV) that someone was kind enough to post, and was successful in running the scripts as per your code provided.

**ItextPdf Example**

**Screenshot 1**
[image]

**Screenshot 2 (image Object is not null)**
[image]

**org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64Example** 
[image]

Comment: You Using ItextPdf Image Class. I am using import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 for decoding and getting values in byte. But at image.scalePercent(15f) i am getting null...

Comment: I've modified the example to include the library you're using and my tests still passed. Can you provide me with the String value you're trying to pass in?